# JSlint Jquery Error - Expected }

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using someone elses WYSIWYG editor code but JSlint says there are two errors. I wonder if someone can help explain / fix them.

This is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/sCATj/40/

The error that JSlint says is:

```
Error:
Problem at line 3 character 40: Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'.
if (!(array instanceof Array)) return;

Problem at line 4 character 25: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined
```

I dont know about jquery. Should I just be putting a } instead of return?

Comment: Please post your code here as well.

Comment: Read the error message. Really. It wants a { in the place of the return. Put the braces around the body of the if.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSLint is a Lint, not a plain syntax checker.

[It requires that all `if` statements are associated with a *block* not a *statement*](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#required)

This is valid JavaScript:

```
if (foo)
    return something;
```

This is more maintainable JavaScript (and demanded by JSLint):

```
if (foo) {
    return something;
}
```

The primary reasoning is that if the code is later edited to add another statement, the editor might not notice that the braces are missing and do this:

```
if (foo)
    bar = foo;
    return something;
```

Which gives the same result as:

```
if (foo) {
    bar = foo;
}
return something;
```

and not the desired:

```
if (foo) {
    bar = foo;
    return something;
}
```

Avoiding shortcuts (especially those which are conditional (you can omit the braces **if** there is only one statement)) is a form of defence programming that reduces the changes of bugs being introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can omit the curly-braces if there is only one statement being made inside an `if` block.

You can safely ignore this 'error'.

Comment: You can "safely" ignore most of JSLint's errors. Most of them are there for a reason and shouldn't be ignored without understanding the motivation behind them.